# CComSafeArray use

Tags: c++, mfc, safearray

I have a Com function:

```
GetData (SAFEARRAY ** pRetVal)
```

I have the following piece of code:

```
SAFEARRAY *ppData = NULL;       
hr = pmyInterface->GetData( &ppData );
CComSafeArray<IUnknown*> pSafeArgs;
pSafeArgs.Attach( ppData );
```

I have to change it, and remove ppData, and also remove the Attach command.

It should be something like this:

```
CComSafeArray<IUnknown*> pSafeArgs;
hr = pmyInterface->GetData( ((SAFEARRAY**)&pSafeArgs )))
```

But this doesn't work. Probably a problem with the release of the CComArray.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does `hr` have an error code?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when creating the CComSafeArray you would specify the type of data that will be held within it, eg:

```
CComSafeArray<char> pSafeArgs;
```

To supply this to your COM function you would do the following:

```
HRESULT hr = pmyInterface->GetData((LPSAFEARRAY)pSafeArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CComSafeArray::GetSafeArrayPtr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s10dhw5.aspx):

```
// Substitute T with the actual type of items 
// in your SAFEARRAY, e.g. CComSafeArray<BYTE>
CComSafeArray<T> safeArgs;

hr = pmyInterface->GetData( safeArgs.GetSafeArrayPtr() );
```

(In general, you should avoid C-style casts in C++ code.)

Comment: In fairness that (LPSAFEARRAY) 'cast' is actually a CComSafeArray operator.

Comment: @dripfeed: The original code was `((SAFEARRAY**)&pSafeArgs))` (with `pSafeArgs` being an instance of `CComSafeArray`). So, first an address is taken with `operator &`, and then it is cast to a `SAFERRAY**`: how is this equivalent to a `CComSafeArray` operator? Moreover, if the OP wanted to call `CComSafeArray::operator LPSAFEARRAY`, then he would better use `static_cast<LPSAFEARRAY>(pSafeArgs)`.